# align R code in TextMate

Tags: r, alignment, textmate

I've recently downloaded the align bundle from github but it is not working as expected. I'm trying to use the bundle to align R code. Let's say I have the following code:

```
foo <- test
foofoofoo <- test
foofoo <- test
```

I want to align the code like this:

```
foo           <- test
foofoofoo     <- test
foofoo        <- test
```

Note alignment is at <-

The align bundle is not aligning code at <-. Is there a way to do this in TextMate?